# master slave exposes technical debt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Using rails and postgresql.

I wrote my app without having in mind to use a master slave configuration.

Now, I've gotten master slave set up in the app and now I'm running into some technical debt. The same process in my app writes to the db and then immediately reads from the db. The read is not taking place on the read db but the data isn't there. Before, this wasn't efficient but it didn't cause any problems because both dbs were the same. Now, this is blowing up in my face.

The problem for me is that its difficult to find all the places in the code where this problem exists. Can someone can please suggest to me a technique to get my tests to run in such a way where the reads and the writes use different dbs that aren't updated so that I can figure out where my issues are?

Other solutions will also be welcomed!

Comment: You can add `replicated_model` to your model to force writes on master and reads on slave, check out the 'master-slave replication' section here, maybe this will help: https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2014/2/4/postgresql-awesomeness-for-rails-developers/

Comment: Thank you for your response but i've gotten master slave setup. The problem is my code is not written in a way that allows master slave to work properly :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend you rethink your master/slave configuration or whether master/slave is even right for your application.

It's not "tech debt" to build a system that assumes data written to persistent store can be read back immediately. It's normal and correct. While you might reasonably be able to avoid the pattern

```
write A, ..., look up A.key
```

with various simple cache schemes, trying to code around e.g.

```
write A, ..., complex query that *might* fetch A
```

requires you to retain a copy of A and determine whether it would satisfy the WHERE clause of the query in separate code, simply because you can't rely on the query results.  Unless your system is very small and simple, trying to do this system-wide will produce a super-complex, fragile, expensive, and ugly code base. I strongly recommend you don't try it.

The usual purpose of a master/slave persistent store organization is to off-line ***read traffic that's not time-dependent on writes***. For example, if your system mines data to produce summaries accessible to users, you'd offline the metric computation and have it mine the slave. This prevents mining queries from drawing resources away from user request handling. The small delay between write on master and copy to slave is no problem.

If your app is struggling because there's too much load on persistent store, you probably want partitioned data (sometimes called sharding), not master/slave. Partitioning can expose you to a different kind of problem: no cross-partition transactions. But this is usually easier to work through than what you're attempting.

Answer (score 0):

After studying this area, I agree with Gene that master slave should only be used for reads that have been written a significant time before the read.

My ORIGINAL concept was that its better to utilize a functional programming style whereby the process retains all the information in the parameters and then doesn't make recourse to the database. The downside of this approach is that the human mind has a hard time with functional programming and in a massive computer program it makes sense to not insist on this added complication.

If you want to write a functional method or process then that is great and very efficient but there shouldn't be anything in the code that insists on this.